# Cross-Browser simulator for testing

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, frontend

I need to test my application on several browser versions, is there any smart way to do that? I need a browser simulator in order to switch between browsers and versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tools

1. [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)
2. [SauceLabs](http://saucelabs.com/)
3. [BrowserLing](https://www.browserling.com/)

Just to name a few.